# My userscript doesn't work and I don't know why (overuse of var keyword)

Tags: javascript, syntax, userscripts

Hey guys/gals I just discovered the dopeness that is userscripts and I wanted to create one. from the limited amount of tutorials online I managed to come up with this.

```
// ==UserScript== 
// @name My add on
// @description A script that adds a green div to the bottom of the page 
// @include http://*
// @grant none
// ==/UserScript== 
function createDiv(){
var userBar=document.createElement('DIV');
var userBar.style.height='80px';
var userBar.style.width='100%';
var userBar.style.backgroundColor='green';
document.body.appendChild(userBar);
}
createDiv();
```

This is just a test script that adds a green div to the bottom of the page. Unfortunately, it does nothing when implemented.

Comment: Is it in a Dom ready?

Comment: Always check the error console!  If you had, you would have seen syntax errors.  Then temporarily eliminate code until you see what breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused because you write always the var in front. You can only do that during declaration.

This is correct:

```
function createDiv(){
    var userBar=document.createElement('DIV');
    userBar.style.height='80px';
    userBar.style.width='100%';
    userBar.style.backgroundColor='green';
    document.body.appendChild(userBar);
}

createDiv();
```

Additionally, since you said you want to add it at the bottom of the site, you might add before adding the element to body:

```
userBar.style.position='absolute';
userBar.style.bottom='50px';
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't event see that. My initial frustration must have blinded me! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
...
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.appendChild(userBar);
```